# What happens if someone force to break you fast

Tags: sawm

Does the fast still count or no or do the person have to fast again for another day. Not about ramadan but broken wallahi

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the force.

If you are at the risk of losing your life then it's permitted to break your fast. But you should repay your missed sawm after the force is over and you should pay the kaffara. And the person who forced you clearly is a sinner and awaits punishment.

[Source](https://www.iium.edu.my/deed/lawbase/risalah_maliki/book23.html#:%7E:text=As%20for%20the%20one%20who,there%20was%20a%20valud%20interpretation.%5D)

> As for the one who breaks his fast by forgetfulness or on the Day of Doubt or is **forced** to break it, and their excuse is removed, then it is obligatory for them to refrain. When the one forced breaks his fast after the compulsion is removed, he must make it up with kaffara unless there was a valud interpretation.

Of course it's important to note that different muftis may have different views on the matter.

Comment: is that only for ramadan

Comment: The reason why I post this question is because I fasting  because an broken Wallahi and I need to make it up and my Dad thinks that im killing myself because I been fasting for 3 days and he didn't know the reason (because I forgot to tell him) so he forced me to eat but after I still try to remain fasting until sunset. so does that still count for fasting?

Comment: So edit your question to include these information and the fact it's not a question about month Ramadan.